# Prompt Windows - Script Back up

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, backup, rar

I need to back up some files processed. For this need to move my files from the `C:\xml\UPLOADING` to the `C:\xml\UPLOADED`. Files that have been moved to `C:\xml\UPLOADED` have to be compressed (.rar or .zip) to a folder with the default name `in10xml_uploaded_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS`. For this did the following command:

```
cd "C:\program files\WinRar"
rar a C:\xml\UPLOADED\in10xml_uploaded_%date%_%time%.rar C:\xml\UPLOADING\*.xml
```

The command is not working the way I need, because I need to move the files from the `C:\xml\UPLOADING` and do a copy (the above command is making a copy) of files in this directory leading to the `C:\xml\UPLOADED` already compressed in `in10xml_uploaded_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS format`. The date and time is also not out in the format I want. How do I solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can move files directly to an archive using the `rar m` command:

```
rar m C:\xml\UPLOADED\in10xml_uploaded_%date%_%time%.rar C:\xml\UPLOADING\*.xml
```

After the above command completes, the files will no longer be in the UPLOADING directory.

cmd.exe doesn't have any facilities for formatting dates. You can get the date format you want by using substrings:

```
echo %date%  (check the current format, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy)
echo %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%  (yyyymmdd)
```

But be careful: if you change your Region Settings in the Control Panel, you'll need to change this batch script to accommodate the new date format.